# Hibernate disable collection fetching

Tags: hibernate

Using latest Hibernate 3...

Have a model where Element class has 2 list collections against a Relation class.  The one being where Element owns (sources) the Relation and the other when it is the destination.

```
 <class name="Element"....>
     ....

     <list name="sourceRelations" ....>
       ...
       <one-to-many class="...Relation" />
     </list>

     <list name="destinationRelations" ....>
       ...
       <one-to-many class="...Relation" />
     </list>
 </class>

 <class name="Relation"....>
     ....
     <many-to-one name="source" class="...Element" ...
        <column name="SOURCEID" sql-type="INTEGER" not-null="true" />
     </many-to-one>
     <many-to-one name="destination" class="...Element" ...
        <column name="DESTINATIONID" sql-type="INTEGER" not-null="true" />
     </many-to-one>
 </class>
```

The mapping is essentially only useful when generating Criteria queries.  Otherwise when fetching an Element (only through a criteria, never via get/load) I never want Hibernate to actually fetch the Relation collections.  Never.  Right now in my code I clean the Element objects before returning them by creating a new Element and transferring over the properties I want propagated (i.e. sourceRelation/destinationRelation never get transferred).  Same goes for criteria queries against Relation objects.  The source/destination properties (i.e. Element) are cleaned.

Is there a way to proxy the Element entity via Hibernate interceptors or using Tuplizers to basically force all Element entities to null out the sourceRelation/destinationRelation properties?

Answer (score 0):

Is mapping the relations collections as lazy="true" not providing the desired behavior?

If that's not the case, then the alternative is to use class inheritance. Have a base class for Element that does not have the collections mapped, to use in those cases you're now manually modifying the returned data, and then a subclass that simply adds those collections, to use when you need the larger amount of data.

Comment: The whole idea not to have to subclass.  The Element/Relation classes should be generic.

Comment: Why is lazy="true" not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202160/hibernate-hql-fetch-only-table-value/6202368#6202368) reminded me of the other approach that will allow you to avoid using subclasses.

Create a constructor that contains just the fields you want, and use it in your HQL like this:

```
select new Element(e.id,...) from Element e...
```

I'm adding a second answer since this one is a different approach than my first answer.

Comment: Cool suggestion.  Using criteria for queries and get for well get.  But if you can do it in HQL then it should be possible with the other APIs.

Will play around and get back to you.  Ever tried your approuch with tupilizers?  Essentially your suggestion is what I am doing in my code.  Creating a new Element and populating with what I want.  It is just that it seems like an extra step and a waste of objects.

Comment: I make heavy use of HQL/JPQL because I like to take advantage of Hibernate's checking of Named Queries on startup as a fail-fast tactic in my development process. I haven't personally experimented much with other approaches.