# Hibernate HQL fetch only table value?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is possible fetch only table value without fetch all the invese collection pesent ni others correlate tables?

example:

```
-------------------
User
-------------------
id int primary key
name varchar 
-------------------

-------------------
Client
-------------------
id int primary key
name varchar
id_user int foreign-key ->User.id
-------------------
```

In HQL query "from User" I want to fetch only users not the entire set of Client.

Comment: This will happen by default if you have lazy-loading enabled and don't call `user.getClients()`. If you need it to happen regardless, use Bivas's solution but beware that attempting to access the Clients will throw an Exception.

Answer (score 2):

it's possible to ask for specific fields in HQL, but it requires to have a matching constructor to enable object creation.

```
class User {
    // ... methods, fields

    User(Long id, String name) {
        // set fields
    }
}
```

and your HQL will look like:
`select new(id, name) from User`